# multiple grep and grouped output

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

input:

```
--------------- 1st block ----------------

info1:AAAAA

random info

random info

random info

info0:"one string"

random info

random info

[...]

info2:"2nd string"


info3:"3rd string"

random info

random info

info4:"4th string"

--------------- 2nd block ----------------

info1:BBBBB

random info

random info

random info

info0:"one string"

random info

random info

[...]

info2:"2nd string" 

info3:"3rd string"

random info

random info


info4:"4th string"

--------------- 3rd block ---------------- 

[...]
```

note: if info0 is the pattern I search I want to grab info0,info1,info2,info3,info4

I can do grep info0 -B 4 (to grab info1), but I cannot do -A x to grab the rest (info2,3,4) because the number of lines can be different from one block to another.

important:

```
 -the output should be grouped by info0

-info0, info2,info3,info4 is always the same, but info1 is always unique (actually info1 is a MAC address). 

-the number of blocks is not limited (there can be 1, 2 , 3, 4,...blocks).

-subsidiary question: within the same command, do the same thing but with info0 carrying different string. For instance: 2 blocks with the same info0, then 3 blocks with another info0 and so on and so forth...

 - I put ----- #block----- in the input to facilitate lecture to the reader, but these lines do not exist in the actual input.
```

wanted output:

```
info0:"one string"

info1:AAAAA

info1:BBBBB 

info2:"2nd string"

info3:"3rd string"

info4:"4th string"
```

what I have done so far

```
output | grep info0 -B 4 -A 23 | grep '\(info1\|info0\|info1\|info2\|info3\|info4\)' >> /tmp/info0
```

23 -> estimated max number of lines of one block

thank you so much folks!

Comment: Please add your efforts which you have put in order to fix this problem in your post too.

Comment: Please wrap your input and output samples in code tags too as it is not clear as of now.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having problem with? There are freelancing sites, if you search for someone to do the job for you.

Comment: If you don't really have a blank line between every line of data in your input and output then fix the example in your question.

Answer (score -1):

I found an uggly but working solution. Let 's say I search info0 and the input is /tmp/input:

```
echo info0;grep info0 -B5 /tmp/input | grep info1;awk '/info0/{flag=1} flag; /info4/{flag=0}' /tmp/input | grep '\(info2\|info3\)' | sort -u
```

Comment: If you could provide neat input and output then this could be done in single command itself I am pretty sure.

Comment: @Ravinder - you just need to copy and past 'input' without '---- # block -----'.The solution works with -B8 with this input, but in bash shell (because of blank lines), it works with -B5 (you just need to get back to 'info1'). Anyway, I am fine with this solution although uggly.

Comment: Happy that you got this working but why I said that we could give better solution in case any one in future referring this post should get good answer though I am not saying this is bad but could be improved, cheers.

Comment: @Ravinder - thanx for spending time on this.